# what does "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 68" mean?

Tags: java, string, exception

I keep getting this error "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 68" while I use the Workbook to get the workbook of the |XL sheet in the filepath .

I had initially thought it had something to do with the storing of filepaths but now thanks to the suggestions below am able to pin point the place where the exception is thrown. The exception is thrown from

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
```

The full code.

```
public void readxls() {

try{
String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\names\\Documents\\details.xls";
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);

// TO get the access to the sheet
Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

// To get the number of rows present in sheet
int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();

// To get the number of columns present in sheet
int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();

for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
System.out.println();



String a = sh.getCell(0, row).getContents();
String b = sh.getCell(1, row).getContents();
String c = sh.getCell(2, row).getContents();
String d = sh.getCell(3, row).getContents(); 
System.out.println("A= "+a+ "B=" +b+ "C=" +c+"D=" +d);
}}

catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}}
```

I want to iterate through the cells in the XL sheet and print it out.

Comment: it means you are trying to get the 67th char of a String that has less than 67 chars

Comment: Are you sure it is this piece of code that throws the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I cannot see any access to char indexes of a `String` here...

Comment: @deHaar I have a list of functions and every other functions throws the right output but the compiler simply throws this exception when executing this function 'readxls() '

Comment: When asking for help regarding Exceptions please always provide a stacktrace.

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

```
try{
   Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\names\\Documents\\details.xls"));
} catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should use File instead of FileInputStream. And if any error occurs, you will see that in you catch block